# Remove nested json object from main json object with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Hi I had an Json Object like that

```
          "clips"[
                {             
                "layers": [
                    {
                        "type": "image-overlay",
                        "path": "http://google.com",
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "slide-in-text",
                        "text": "Some Bags"
                    },
                   
                ]
            },
            {
                "duration": 3,
                "layers": [
                    {
                        "type": "image",
                        "path": "http://google.com",
                        "resizeMode": "stretch",
                        "start": 0,
                        "stop": 3,
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "image-overlay",
                        "path": "***vendor**logo*0",
                        "zoomDirection": "in",
                        "width": 0.7,
                    }
                ]
            }
           ]
```

I want to remove json object which contain,

> *** vendor ** logo*0

So I want to remove only this object:

```
                    {
                        "type": "image-overlay",
                        "path": "***vendor**logo*0",
                        "zoomDirection": "in",
                        "width": 0.7,
                    }
```

My code snipped like that:

```
jsonObj.clips.map((clip, index)=>{
    clip.layers.map((layer, index=>{
         if(layer.path === '***vendor**logo*0'){
           //Remove layer
          }
    })
})
```

How Can I do this with nodejs? Please Help!

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Have you tried `delete object[1].layers[1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could return all other items except the one you don't want

```
const json = /* your json array */

const newJson = json.map(node => node.layers.filter(layer => layer.path !== "***vendor**logo*0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't very clear, so I had to guess a bit. But here is a potential solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

Currently, it only works with arrays, but it could easily be generalized. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const input = { clips: [{ layers: [{ type: 'image-overlay', path: 'http://google.com' }, { type: 'slide-in-text', text: 'Some Bags' }] }, { duration: 3, layers: [{ type: 'image', path: 'http://google.com', resizeMode: 'stretch', start: 0, stop: 3 }, { type: 'image-overlay', path: '***vendor**logo*0', zoomDirection: 'in', width: 0.7 }] }] };

const rm = (obj, v) => objectScan(['**[*].*'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ gparent, gproperty, value }) => {
    if (value === v) {
      gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(obj);

console.log(rm(input, '***vendor**logo*0'));
// => true

console.log(input);
// => { clips: [ { layers: [ { type: 'image-overlay', path: 'http://google.com' }, { type: 'slide-in-text', text: 'Some Bags' } ] }, { duration: 3, layers: [ { type: 'image', path: 'http://google.com', resizeMode: 'stretch', start: 0, stop: 3 } ] } ] }
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)